# Main Questions link constantly displays "That's a miss"

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Clicking the main *Questions* link here or in S/O navigates to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tagFilter=all&mode=any
```

which is always displaying the cache related "*That's a miss*" battleships image. F5 or clicking *new* shows what's expected.

This was [intermittent before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297688/website-new-navigation-thats-a-miss-error-on-initial-question-navigation), but now is constant.

Comment: we are on it right now

Comment: Clicking on the tags has the same result. I used the tags to refresh the question list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.7.24.3605` on MSE/MSO, `2015.7.24.2747` on sites).